# Conv2DSlowBackpropInput: input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth

Tags: python, tensorflow, lambda, keras, conv-neural-network

This code doesn't work (I get the error in the title):

```py
def conv1d_transpose(x, filters, kernel_width=25, stride=4):
    inp = K.expand_dims(x, axis=1)
    return Conv2DTranspose(
        filters,
        (1, kernel_width),
        strides=(1, stride),
        padding='same'
        )(inp)[:, 0]
deconv_layer0 = Lambda(lambda x: conv1d_transpose(x, c*d))(relu_layer0)
```

This code does work:

```py
expanded_layer0 = Lambda(lambda x: K.expand_dims(x, axis=1))(relu_layer0)
conv1d_t_layer0 = Conv2DTranspose(c*d, (1, 25), strides=(1, 4), padding='same')(expanded_layer0)
slice_layer0 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, 0])(conv1d_t_layer0)
```

Why not? Do they not both achieve the same thing?

Comment: What are `c` and `d` values?

Comment: @thushv89 `c=16` and `d=64`

Comment: What's the shape of `relu_layer0`?

Comment: `(None, 16, 1024)`

Comment: @HarryStuart, which TF version is this?

Comment: Version is TF=2.0